# Jupyter Notebook: "unable to connect to Kernel"

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have just started to use virtual environment and tried to create one for Jupyter Notebook, and almost succeeded but when I tried to open a new notebook it gave the error "unable to connect to kernel or server":

[image: Here it is:]

Refreshing the browser, clearing the browser cache , restarting anaconda etc also did't ***fix the problem!***

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens most times, try restarting anaconda it should fix the server issues, also clear browser cache.